# Typescript reactjs Can't spread props to input tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, spread-syntax

I have a reusable Input Component that I use throughout my application

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from "./Input.module.css";

interface Props {
  input: Object;
  label: string;
  custom: Object;
  meta: {
    touched: boolean;
    error: boolean;
  }
}

    const Input: React.SFC<Props> = ({
      input,
      label,
      custom,
    }) => (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <input {...input} {...custom} />
          <span className={styles.highlight} />
          <span className={styles.bar} />
          <label>{label}</label>
        </div>
      );

    export default Input;
```

I am in the process of converting an old javascript project from javascript to typescript. Everything works as it should except for when I spread props into the input tag, then typescript returns this error.

[image]

Any idea what's causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript Object type has properties like "isPropertyOf", "hasOwnValue" and more that not suit to input element,
try to change to something like:

```
 input: {
test: string,
id: Number
}
```